# Is "grounds" ever used for things other than coffee?

Tags: word-usage

I've never seen the word *[grounds](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grounds)* (meaning *sediment/dregs*; definition 12 only) used to describe anything other than coffee; are there any other usages of *grounds* of that meaning, or has it become a coffee-word?

> **12.  grounds,** dregs or sediment: *coffee grounds.*

Comment: I did. I found it difficult to accept a self-reported Pensyltuckian who reads a gabillion real pages a year never hears the word "grounds" except for coffee. I resisted the urge to say that trolls lived under the grounds, but since you clarified, I removed the downvote and gave you back your 2 points ;).

Comment: *Ad hominem*, and I can't [strike back](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/4552/horatio)? ;)  BTW, it's not the rep I'm worried about - it's the reputation.  Anyway, I hope I don't come across as a Penselturkial troll now!

Comment: I found an entry for "tobacco grounds", but only on the Urban Dictionary entry for "Hillbilly Hotpocket". Ick. I'm not providing a link, and I highly suggest you just trust me on this one.

Comment: The OED has quotations that associate it with beer and tea, but those are all pre-1900.

Comment: I immediately thought of Hofstadter's "Godel, Escher, Bach" - "The grounds are excellent", but that really doesn't address this question...

Comment: to be fair, before your edit, it was pretty outrageous. And I'm in Pennsyltucky right now.

Comment: grounds for divorce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A Concise Etymological Dictionary of the English Language](http://books.google.com/books?id=wRGhnkZq3HQC&pg=PA223&dq=grounds%20dregs%20-coffee&hl=en&ei=9s54TvnBBKni4QSAu93vCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=grounds%20dregs%20-coffee&f=false) (Walter W. Skeat, 1910) says grounds comes not from having being ground, but from being left over at the bottom.

> **grounds**, dregs. (E.) So called from being at the bottom. Cf. Gael. *grunndas*, lees, from *grunnd*, bottom., ground; Irish *gruntas*, dregs, from *grunnt*, the bottom.

An [1825 patent](http://books.google.com/books?id=wNAcAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA67&dq=%2bgrounds%20dregs&hl=en&ei=gM94TqqmGubP4QTi8amYDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg) talks of:

> an improved apparatus for the purpose of beneficially separating the infusion of tea or coffee from the grounds or dregs.

[A French and English dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=9EI_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PT288&dq=%2bgrounds%20dregs&hl=en&ei=gM94TqqmGubP4QTi8amYDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%2bgrounds%20dregs&f=false) (Randle Cotgrave, 1673) translates:

> Fondrilles: The grounds, lees; or dregs of liquor.

There are definitions of sediment and faeces that give grounds as a synonym.

[The justice of the peace, and parish officer, Volume 2](http://books.google.com/books?id=EwRAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22liquor%20grounds%22%20%20-coffee&hl=en&ei=rdh4TvanNNDQ4QSRiu3wCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22liquor%20grounds%22%20%20-coffee&f=false) (Richard Burn, 1814):

> Penalty on brewer receiving stale beer grounds, or mixing with any liquor except malt and hops, 100l.

[Beer and ale grounds](http://www.google.com/search?num=20&hl=en&tbo=1&biw=1024&bih=509&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&q=%22beer%20grounds%22%20OR%20%22ale%20grounds%22&btnG=Search) were not uncommon in recipes, laws for unscrupulous landlords, instructions for making files, as an ingredient for sloughing ulcer treatments, medical comparisons with vomit.

But [nowadays](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=coffee%20grounds,tea%20grounds,beer%20grounds,ale%20grounds,liquor%20grounds,chicory%20grounds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it is chiefly applied to coffee:

[image: Ngrams]

Answer (score 2):

Nay, it is not a coffee word only; behold: [Chicory Grounds!](http://www.cofei.com/reviews/roasted-chicory.html)

In my opinion, chicory is a coffee substitute, so "grounds" remains a "coffee word" still.

Comment: If you google ["chicory grounds"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22chicory+grounds%22), you get 228 results, though, as opposed to the 2140000 for ["coffee grounds"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q="coffee+grounds").

Comment: I actually offered that up as a semi-serious answer. In my opinion, chicory is a coffee substitute, so "grounds" remains a "coffee word" still.

Comment: @drɱ65: Obviously coffee is by far the most common, and as Jeff says, chicory is basically a poor man's coffee anyway. But *"cocoa grounds"*, for example, gets over 1100 hits on Google, and they nearly all seem to be for the "dregs" meaning. The point is, it's not *only* coffee, so Jeff is right (and gets a brownie point from me! :)