# What do you call freshly ground coffee versus the coffee that has been brewed?

Tags: semantics

Some people refer to ***grinds*** as the coffee that comes out of the grinder, and ***grounds*** as the spent grinds you're left with after brewing.

Is this nomenclature correct?

Comment: Setting aside the question of "correctness", it may be of interest that [the term "grounds" in the sense of "dregs" is apparently not originally related in etymology to the verb "grind", but instead developed from the noun *ground* based on the position of the grounds beneath the liquid](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/42615/77227).

Answer (score -1):

> Some people refer to grinds as the coffee that comes out of the grinder,

This is a misuse. "grind" (noun, countable) is (From the OED):**The size of the particles of a powder, e.g. ground coffee.**

1922   W. H. Ukers All about Coffee xxv. 402/1   A mixture of a very fine with a coarse grind gives the best results in the cup.

1959   Glossary of Packaging Terms (B.S.I.) 34   Grind, the size of the particles of which moulding powder is composed, generally graded according to the portions retained by different mesh sizes.

Comment: Interesting. So to the second half of the question, what do you call the spent grinds left after brewing?

Comment: "Grounds" https://www.thespruce.com/using-coffee-grounds-in-your-garden-2539864 "How to Use Coffee Grounds in Your Garden"

Comment: The following training document for baristas defines “the grind” as “the consistency of the ground coffee” (p.30) and even capitalize “the Grind” (p.32) when using it more broadly to mean “the product/result of grinding the coffee beans” rather than simply its consistency or grain size. The 77-page document does not anywhere use “grinds” to refer to the ground beans. https://shortcoursesau.edu.au/pdf/sca/Barista-Coffee-Workbook.pdf

Comment: Notice that the OED refers to sources that pre-date the significant “waves” of change in modern coffee brewing techniques and culture (as described here: https://prima-coffee.com/coffee-glossary#first). But this may or may not be relevant to the answer, but notice there are no meshes in use in the modern context.