# Ground or grounded - and why?

Tags: british-english, participles

In the sentence,

> This particular discipline was ground by the strict protocols of its predecessors.

Why is it ground and not grounded? To me it feels like I should use the infinitive 'ground' as a participle but I'm now second-guessing. They are both participles but seem to sound more natural in different places. Is there a rule I'm missing?

*The grounded plane began to take off once the storm had cleared.*

Vs.

*I prefer coffee beans to ground coffee.*

Which is correct, which is more natural, and why?

Comment: They are different words. *Grind* – *ground* – put through a mill, but *grounded* – kept on the ground. (I recall a joke: Customer: "This coffee tastes like mud!" Waiter: "Well it was only ground this morning.") Anyway the first sentence means "shaped/developed by ..."

Comment: ...and the choice of the word *ground* gives the sentence a harsh, unforgiving feeling.

Answer (score 3):

As @WeatherVane pointed out, you're dealing with two different verbs, derived from two different English sources, with little common meaning -- just enough for jokes.

One is the irregular (aka "strong") verb ***to  grind, ground, ground***
(the first principal part is the infinitive form, second is past tense, third is past participle)
which means 'abrade by friction' and often takes a resultant phrase after the object, like

- *The glaciers ground the rock into sand.* (past tense here)

The other verb is the regular denominal causative verb ***to ground, grounded, grounded***
which means 'force to (come to) be in one place' (including, for airplane objects, force to land or to stay on the ground)  and is often used in the passive, as in

- *You're grounded!*

This one is regular, as denominal causatives usually are, and *ground* is the only form the two verbs have in common. It's interesting that the two verbs still don't conflict, because *ground* can't be the infinitive or present tense of *to grind*, but it can't be the past or past participle of *to ground*, either. If you know what it means, you know the correct form.

Comment: @x30 And just to boil it down: *Unless* the intended meaning is that the protocols "grind" the discipline (perhaps metaphorically)... " *grounded* is right and *ground* is wrong. (Also, yet another usage is "to ground [something] **in** [something else]," meaning to provide a firm foundation or contextualization, which I suspect is the most applicable one here, as in "This particular discipline was grounded in the strict protocols of its predecessors.")

Comment: The ground is part of daily existence for everyone, and thus available for many different metaphors, which cohere nicely. The ground is, after all, made up of ground-up rock.

Comment: Which naturally leads to the age-old question debated by generations of rabbis: [coffee grounds or grinds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525230/what-do-you-call-freshly-ground-coffee-versus-the-coffee-that-has-been-brewed) :-)